# How to Store Dynamic Edit text Value in Hashmap in android

Tags: android, hashmap

I have multiple dynamic edittext box..

```
TableLayout ll_list = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tbl);
for(i=0;i < Sizedd; i++)
{
EditText ed_comm = new EditText(this);
ll_list.addView(ed_comm);
}
```

how to store its value in hashmap?

Comment: use the id of the edittext as the key and the text as the value?

Comment: Don't create duplicate question. You have already asked this question not 2 hours back.

Comment: Create hashmap `using HashMap<String, String> map_name=new HashMap<String, String>();` and put value using  `map_name.put(a_string,another_string);` use `edittext_id.getText()` to get value from **EditText**.

Comment: Can any one provide example for user1153176

Comment: Hope my answer could be of some help at least.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is, set Tag for each EditText you create and store their data using Text Watcher. I am not good at this. But try to modify my snippet accordingly.

First declare a HashMap Globally,

```
public  HashMap<Integer,String> myList=new HashMap<Integer,String>();
```

And

```
TableLayout ll_list = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tbl);
for(i=0;i < Sizedd; i++)
{
EditText ed_comm = new EditText(this);
ed_comm.setTag(i); // By this you have set an Tag to the editText and hence you can find out which editText it is, in the TextWatcher implementation. 
ll_list.addView(ed_comm);

ed_comm.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                        int after) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    Log.i("After  Text","Called");
                     myList.put(ed_comm.getTag(),s.toString().trim());
                }
            });
}
```

That's it. You have stored the values to a hashMap. This TextWatcher will be called for every text you enter into your EditText. So your hashmap will be updated anytime.

Now to fetch the data from Hashmap, do this,,

```
Iterator i = myList.iterator();
            while (i.hasNext()) {
                    System.out.println(i.next());
            }
```

Comment: i have button and when i click button its call system.out.Println(myList); its shows out put {2=zxc}

Comment: Yeah. you shuld have entered text only in the second edit text alone. try editing all the EditText and check